# Do DB constraints cause Ruby to crash and should I rescue them or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, exception

I'm reading an article which says all Exceptions cause Ruby to crash.
http://blog.honeybadger.io/a-beginner-s-guide-to-exceptions-in-ruby/

I've got some DB schema constraints:

```
create_table :options_sets do |t|
    t.boolean :shared, :null => false
end
```

So when I create a new options_set that violates the constraint, causing the exception, I don't know how to check whether the server has restarted, but it doesn't look like it to me.

```
OptionsSet.create()
```

Error Msg:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "shared" violates not-null constraint
```

I've also read many times that "exceptions should not be expected" and that you shouldn't rely exclusively on model validation for various reasons (like race conditions). So it seems to me that this is an exception that must be expected sometimes.

So, should I be rescuing this exception or should it be handled in another way?

Comment: *"that you shouldn't rely exclusively on model validation for various reasons (like race conditions)"* while this can be true in some cases (under heavy load) it definitely has nothing to do with this situation. Whether or not an attribute is set to a non null value is not a race condition unless of course your shared boolean is based on some logic that would need to check the database to confirm its sharedness and you are experiencing extremely high volume. Basically not an optimization you need to concern yourself with right now. Just validate that it is not `nil` and you are good to go

Comment: Note that your example is a schema level validation, not a model validation.  In a comment to one of the answers, Chloe referred you to the actual model validation statement, "validates :shared, presence: true".  The two are very different and how they are handled differ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rails handles all otherwise unhandled exceptions and turns them into HTML error pages. Ruby does not "crash" or restart just because you failed to rescue an exception in your Rails application.

> So, should I be rescuing this exception or should it be handled in another way?

You should be using validations in your model to prevent you from reaching database-level exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that also mean that I should not bother rescuing this kind of thing at all? I do also have model validations

Comment: Don't `rescue` that. Doesn't look like model validations in the question example. Add the validations for `validates :shared, presence: true`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you see here is one that is caused by a faulty programming statement. If you have a bare

```
OptionsSet.create()
```

in your code, this statement **is** the error and it should be fixed. No need to rescue / handle anything.
If, however this exception could be caused by **user input** or other program state, e.g.

```
OptionsSet.create(shared: some_expression_which_may_evaluate_to_nil)
```

then you **should** handle the exception to allow your application to return a meaningful error message to the user, allowing him/her to correct the input.